# gitから複数のリモートリポジトリにプッシュしたい

Tags: git

gitから複数のリモートリポジトリにプッシュしたいと考えて調べたところ、git configファイルに以下のようにURLを2つ設定してプッシュしてみましたが、

1つ目のものはプッシュされるのですが
2つ目に書いたものは反映されず、ログ（プッシュコマンド後に表示されるログ）にもでてきません。

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git
        url = sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

urlを入れ替えてテストしたところ、両方に反映されたのでsshでの接続などはうまくいっていそうな気がしますが、他に確認するポイントなどありましたらご教授いただけましたら嬉しいです。

---

### 捕捉情報

sakuraのほうはさくらのレンタルサーバにて以下のサイトを参考に構成を組んでいます。
https://tapioca-hiroyuki.net/?blog=git0320

ベアリポジトリを設置してそこでpushを受け
hookを設定してノンベア（本番公開用ディレクトリ）でpullする
という流れで組んでいます。

現状`git push origin master`を実行すると以下のようなログが表示されます。

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 332 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2), completed with 2 local objects.
To git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git
   3452346es2..456h8b2  master -> master
fatal: Unable to create '/var/www/html/xxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': ????????
```

※最後の`????????`の部分はgitをバージョンアップする前は`permission denied`と表示されていました

Answer (score 6):

`git remote -v` コマンドを実行すると次のような出力になっているでしょうか。originのpushに対して2行出力されるのが想定された設定かと思います。

```
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git (push)
origin  sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git (push)
```

---

質問文中にあるように`url`属性を追加するのは次のようなコマンドで行え、たしかに動作するようです(v2.11.0)

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git
git remote set-url --add origin sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git
```

が、後述参考リンクやmanを見る限り、複数のpushを行うには次のように`pushurl`属性を設定する方がより適切なように感じました。

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git
```

---

参考:

> The <pushurl> is used for pushes only. It is optional and defaults to <url>.

[`git-push`のman](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)より。`url`属性値は`pushurl`が存在しない時のデフォルト値(なので複数デフォルト値があるというのは変な感じ…？)。

- [git - pull/push from multiple remote locations - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12795747/4506703)

Comment: 検証が遅れまして申し訳ありません。<br>
回答ありがとうございます！  
git remote -vの結果はおっしゃる通りの表示になっております。  
`  
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git (fetch)  
origin  git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git (push)  
origin  sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git (push)  
`

Comment: gitのバージョンが古かったのでアップデートしました。  
（ローカルのみ2.2.0にしました）  
pushのコマンドありがとうございました。  
そういう意味だったんですね！勉強になりました！  
ご提示いただいたコマンドを実行し  
configファイルが以下のように書き換わっていることを確認できました。  
  
`
[remote "origin"]  
        url = git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git  
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
        pushurl = git@github.com:xxxx/xxxx.git  
        pushurl = ssh://sakura@sakusaku.sakura.ne.jp/yyyy/yyyy.git  
`

Comment: その後add→commit→push origin masterしてみましたがgitのほうへは上がるのですがsakuraのほうへは上がりません。sakuraのほうは補足情報がありましたので追記させていただきます。また以下のエラーも検索してみたのですが原因と解決方法がわからずにおります。こちらも捕捉として一応書かせていただきます。わかりずらい部分などありましたらご指摘お願いいたします。可能な限り調査報告させていただきます。また何かお心当たりがありましたらよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 改めて質問文を読み返したところ「urlを入れ替えてテストしたところ…」の部分の理解を私が誤っていました。無駄な確認をさせてしまってすみません。
クライアントサイドは問題無さそう、ということですね。
補足として記載されているエラーですが、permission deniedということであれば、文字通り書き込み権限が存在しないのではないかと考えます。原因は、pushしようとしているユーザ(`sakura`でしょうか)とは異なるユーザで`git init`を行い、権限設定がデフォルトのまま、といったことが考えられます。
権限については、参照されているリンク先に書かれている参考リンク[ベアリポジトリとノンベアリポジトリ：実践編〜GitでWordPressのテーマを管理](http://www.nekotricolor.com/entry/practice-of-bare-and-non-bare-repository-manage-wordpress-themes-with-git)の「権限の問題」節に言及があります。
いずれにせよ、さくらサーバ側の設定の問題かと思われますので、一旦(通常通り)1リポジトリへのpushを試み、正常に行えたことを確認した後、2リポジトリへの同時push設定を行う方が問題を切り分けやすいかと考えます。

Comment: 度々のコメントありがとうございます！その後リモートリポジトリをすべて再構築し、ご教授いただきました--pushオプションにて設定、さらにサーバのベアリポジトリのhookのパーミッションを設定したところ希望通り2つのリポジトリにpushすることができました。確認せずに再構築してしまったので原因が特定できませんでしたが、おそらく--pushオプションを使っていなかったこと、hookファイルのパーミッションが原因の可能性が高いと踏んでいます。長々とお付き合いいただきましてありがとうございました。良い勉強をさせていただきました。