# git pushでエラーが表示されます。

Tags: git

`git push`でエラーが表示され、原因と対処法が見つけられずまたこちらに来てしまいました。

### エラー

virtualbox内のローカルリポジトリからリモートにpushする際にローカルで出ているエラーになります。リモートはgithubとsakuraレンタルサーバのベアリポジトリです。

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': cannot lock ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master': Unable to create '/var/www/html/xxxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock': ????????
```

---

### 現状

git push でちゃんとリモートにはpushできているのですが、こちらのエラーが表示されます。

以前は???????の部分がpermission deniedだったのですが、gitのバージョンを上げてから?に変わりました。（yumインストールの1.7を削除し手動インストールの2.7を入れた）

またmasterというファイルはあるのですがmaster.lockというファイルがwinspc等で見ていても見当たりません。

---

### 環境

ローカルリポジトリから2つのリモートリポジトリに一気にpushできるように設定しています。
一つはgithubのプライベートリポジトリ

もうひとつは下記のサイトを参考にsakuraサーバ内にベアリポジトリを作成して、ノンベアリポジトリ（本番公開用ディレクトリ）でpullしています。
[Gitのリモートリポジトリにプッシュすると自動的にWebサイトが更新されるリポジトリを作成する](https://tapioca-hiroyuki.net/?blog=git0320)

詳細は構築の際にこちらでお世話になった質問があります。
[gitから複数のリモートリポジトリにプッシュしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31569/git%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E8%A4%87%E6%95%B0%E3%81%AE%E3%83%AA%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B8%E3%83%88%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AB%E3%83%97%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

---

### 試してみたこと

.git以下の管理者をapacheにしてみたり
.git/refs/remotes/origin/masterの
パーミッションを777に設定してみたり
しましたが変化はありませんでした。

色々検索してもしかすると`git push -u origin master`の際にconfigファイルに追加された？以下のところが関係あるのかな。。。
という気もしますがその先手がかりが思いつきませんでした。

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

またお知恵を拝借できましたら幸いです。
何卒宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「パーミッションを777に設定してみたり」というのはリモートのリポジトリの話ですか?

Comment: わかりづらく申し訳ありません。ローカルリポジトリの話です。エラーについてもローカルからpushする際に出ております。質問編集しますm(_)m

Comment: ローカルリポジトリにブランチを追加することはできますでしょうか?

Comment: リモートがgithubとsakuraレンタルサーバというのはどういうことですか?originはどちらを指していますか?どちらにpushしたときにエラーがでますか?

Comment: 度々説明が足りず申し訳ありません。質問を編集させていただきました。originは両方を指していて、両方に対して同じエラーメッセージが出ています。Unable to create '/var/www/html/xxxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/master.lock'こちらのパスがローカルのものなのでローカルの問題なのか！？と予測していますがリモートも関係ありそうでしょうか？また何かお心当たりがありましたらコメントいただければ嬉しいです。

Comment: /var/www/html/xxxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/ への読み書き権限はありますか？

Comment: /var/www/html/xxxx/.git/refs/remotes/origin/配下に.lockファイルがなにかありませんか？

Comment: .git以下のファイルの所有者をapacheにしてパーミッションを777にしてみたらエラーが出なくなりました。ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

`.git`以下のファイルの所有者を`apache`にしてパーミッションを`777`にしてみたらエラーが出なくなりました。

([質問者さん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19992/rnejrhxafxmjy)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/31659/git-push%E3%81%A7%E3%82%A8%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99/51406#comment30805_31659)より)